# TableViewController not scrolling up correctly

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, after the user has clicked on a button, a UITableViewController comes up from the bottom of the screen and overs 2/3 of the screen. The table is filled with data but I can't scroll up to see the rest of the data.

```
import UIKit

class CityTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    var cities: [String] = ["New York City", "Montreal", "San Francisco", "Paris", "Lisbon", "London", "Philadelphia", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Atlanta"]

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        self.transitioningDelegate = self
    }

    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {

        return CityPop(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
         self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
        //automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return cities.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CityCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = cities[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Goku", size: 33.9)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }

}

class CityPop: UIPresentationController {

    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {

        let containerFrame = self.containerView!.frame

        return CGRect(x: 0, y: containerFrame.height/3, width: containerFrame.width, height: containerFrame.height)
    }
}
```

[image]

Instead of using a making my TableView and subclass of a UIPresentationController, is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this piece of is the problematic block.

```
return CGRect(x: 0, y: containerFrame.height/3, width: containerFrame.width, height: containerFrame.height)
```

**The system will display the scroll only when data couldn't able to fit the given content size.** here actually you are giving the full-screen height to the view controller which will enough to show all the city names.  you need to change the height properly in such a way that it should in the screen bounds.

change this to

```
return CGRect(x: 0, y: containerFrame.height/3, width: containerFrame.width, height: 2*(containerFrame.height/3))
```

Comment: I agree with Kumar (voted). It looks like the frame of your `CityTableViewController` extends off the bottom of the screen. The table view thinks it doesn't need to scroll since the contents fit in it's frame. It doesn't know that that frame goes off-screen.

Comment: Yes.exactly. Just update the code with one I mentioned. it will resolve.

Comment: Only the person who asked the question can do that.

Comment: Oh this works nicely! Thanks! Can you explain why you divided the height by 3 and then multiply it by 2?

Comment: I can answer that: You make the height of the table view 1/3 less than the whole height of the frame.  `1 - 1/3 = 2/3`. @LampPost, since Kumar's answer solved your problem you should click the checkmark to accept it.